# Fastreport Problem in Sum [Line#]+[Memo1.Value]

Tags: fastreport

In Fastreport Using This Expression
Incorrect result

```
[Line#]+[Memo1.Value]
```

Result

`1+25`

Answer (score 0):

It was solved this way

`[<Line#>+Memo1.Value]`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).